# How many times must you roll a die in order to be $99\%$ sure that it is fair?

Tags: probability, statistics, dice

How many times must you roll a die to be within $99\%$ confidence that it is fair? What if you were to use a die with more sides?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57624/how-many-rolls-do-i-need-to-determine-if-my-dice-are-fair?rq=1 might help

Comment: Is a die that comes up with heads $\frac{1}{100000000000}$ times *more* than it comes up tails fair? Because even if you say "the die is either exactly fair or biased exactly in this way, with probability 50% each", you're going to have to do a *lot* of trials before you get any noticeable information on which case we're in.

Comment: If my die landed on heads, I'd be rather concerned!

Comment: Dice can land on $\;1,2,3,4,5,6\;$, coins can land on heads or tails.

Comment: In other words, we need a definition of fair. Do you mean, for example, that the prob of any side coming up must be within $10^{-6}$ of $\frac{1}{6}$?

Comment: @Joan Absolute majority of dice never land on $1$. or $6$. They land on a a group of dots.

Comment: @A.S. In fact, I think they mostly land on tables. and some other times on the floor, and even less times on rugs.

Comment: mostly on floors is my experience. Btw as noted in the first comment this is a duplicate.